# Access spring security from second application

Tags: spring, security

I have two applications, each located on it's own server. Both of them use Spring security with the standart settings. 
The problem that I need to access first application through the second one. I need to send password and login to the first application when logging in the second.
Can somebody help with samples or tips please? Thank you.
My spring-security.xml in both applications:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none" />

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="hey" password="there" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use CAS for this instead of trying to access or pass user/pass across application.

please refer this [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/cas.html) to get understanding how to use CAS in this kind of scenario.

Comment: Thank you for response, but maybe there is an easier way to solve this? Or spring security has no such features for this situation to avoid additional plugins? Thank you.

Comment: another option can be use cookie to store auth detail from one app and ask other app to use remember-me.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to mention that applications are located on different servers. I am sorry, is this way still possible? And is CAS able to help?

Comment: even if server are different but if they share same domain name then cookie solution can be used. CAS will work in almost in all cases.

Comment: The servers have different domain names. Now I see that there is CAS left to solve this situation. Probably should start working with it from now on. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: welcome, as mentioned by @Xaerxess accept answer if it helps.

Comment: Found one more way to solve it. IF somebody else will have the same trouble. http://www.jpalace.org/docs/technotes/spring/rest-security.html